# error : Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter

i have the error in the title on my app.
It says it comes from there :

```
Future <Jack> Get_Amount_Jackpot() async {
// SERVER LOGIN API URL
var url2 = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/get_jackpot_lottosport.php';

// Starting Web API Call.
var response2 = await http.get(url2,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

// Getting Server response into variable.
Jack jackpots;

var jsondata2 = json.decode(response2.body);

String jackpot7;
String jackpot14;

for (var u in jsondata2) {
  jackpot7=u["j7"];
  jackpot14=u["j14"];
}

jackpots=Jack(jackpot7, jackpot14);

return jackpots;

}
```

"Jack" est une classe définie ci - dessous :

```
class Jack {

  final String j7;
  final String j14;

  const Jack(this.j7,this.j14);
}
```

The api return in jsondata2 this result :

[{j14: 0, j7: 0}]

Do you see any error ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API result `[{j14: 0, j7: 0}]` contains `int` values but your Model has `String`

You model should be

```
class Jack {

  final int j7;
  final int j14;

  const Jack(this.j7,this.j14);
}
```

and your api functions should be

```
Future <Jack> Get_Amount_Jackpot() async {
   // SERVER LOGIN API URL
   var url2 = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/get_jackpot_lottosport.php';

   // Starting Web API Call.
   var response2 = await http.get(url2,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

   // Getting Server response into variable.
   Jack jackpots;

   var jsondata2 = json.decode(response2.body);

   String jackpot7;
   String jackpot14;

   for (var u in jsondata2) {
     jackpot7=u["j7"].toString();
     jackpot14=u["j14"].toString();
   }

   jackpots=Jack(jackpot7, jackpot14);

   return jackpots;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

String jackpot7;
String jackpot14;

to

int jackpot7;
int jackpot14;

Answer (score 0):

i have just change the data api type in float and it works now